# How to upload sigmajs gephi export files to a server? [javascript files w/ css and index.html that I need to point to]

Tags: html, css, gephi, sigma.js

I'm trying to upload my sigmajs export from gephi to a website, my GitHub pages, but I'm having trouble uploading them.

Can somebody explain what to do? I uploaded the folder and tried to point it to index.html, but my graph does not show up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a repo called `accountname.github.io` and push all the files there. Substitute `accountname` above with your GitHub username